# Unable to connect to Azure VPN on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I have one Azure P2S VPN gateway configured for my subscription. I am able to connect to it from any windows machine with no error.
I want to connect to it through Ubuntu Machine. So I followed steps mentioned on below link and set up a new VPN connection on my ubuntu machine.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-azure-cert

I have set VPN connection on ubuntu machine using strongswan network manager.

When I am trying to connect to that VPN I am getting error as below:

```
Aug 21 16:30:15 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 gnome-shell[1423]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for Skype1_75
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1566385256.5576] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674" name="ABC" pid=1423 uid=1000 result="success"
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 gnome-shell[1015]: JS ERROR: TypeError: item is undefined#012setActiveConnections/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1520:17#012setActiveConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1517:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_syncVpnConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1855:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1566385256.5678] vpn-connection[0x55c7acd9e160,8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674,"ABC",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1566385256.5883] vpn-connection[0x55c7acd9e160,8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674,"ABC",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 05[CFG] received initiate for NetworkManager connection ABC
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 05[CFG] using CA certificate, gateway identity 'azuregateway-6a1d0030-7c34-4d1d-879c-c52b5e3ead2e-a0635e20e3c5.vpn.azure.com'
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 05[IKE] initiating IKE_SA ABC[5] to 13.xx.xxx.xx
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 05[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 05[NET] sending packet: from 10.55.1.49[36932] to 13.xx.xxx.xx[500] (726 bytes)
Aug 21 16:30:56 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1566385256.6041] vpn-connection[0x55c7acd9e160,8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674,"ABC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)


Aug 21 16:31:00 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 06[IKE] retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
Aug 21 16:31:00 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 06[NET] sending packet: from 10.55.1.49[36932] to 13.xx.xxx.xx[500] (726 bytes)
Aug 21 16:31:07 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 16[IKE] retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0
Aug 21 16:31:07 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 16[NET] sending packet: from 10.55.1.49[36932] to 13.xx.xxx.xx[500] (726 bytes)
Aug 21 16:31:20 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 07[IKE] retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
Aug 21 16:31:20 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 07[NET] sending packet: from 10.55.1.49[36932] to 13.xx.xxx.xx[500] (726 bytes)
Aug 21 16:31:44 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 14[IKE] retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0
Aug 21 16:31:44 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 14[NET] sending packet: from 10.55.1.49[36932] to 13.xx.xxx.xx[500] (726 bytes)
Aug 21 16:31:57 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm[12235]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Aug 21 16:31:57 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <warn>  [1566385317.3620] vpn-connection[0x55c7acd9e160,8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674,"ABC",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
Aug 21 16:31:57 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 charon-nm: 15[IKE] destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
Aug 21 16:31:57 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <warn>  [1566385317.3696] vpn-connection[0x55c7acd9e160,8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674,"ABC",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Aug 21 16:31:57 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1566385317.3698] vpn-connection[0x55c7acd9e160,8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674,"ABC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Aug 21 16:31:57 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1566385317.3699] vpn-connection[0x55c7acd9e160,8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674,"ABC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Aug 21 16:31:57 siladmin-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[784]: <warn>  [1566385317.3722] vpn-connection[0x55c7acd9e160,8fc05b29-e5c9-47eb-a3ac-9d5d487b9674,"ABC",0]: VPN plugin: failed: login-failed (0)
```

I also checked the status for firewall on my machine and it is inactive.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Found any solution for the above issue ?